# Android NumberFormatException: Invalid Double - except the value is a valid Double

Tags: java, android, parsing, double, numberformatexception

So the other day, the following error popped up in the Crashes section of the Google Play Developer Console:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "−0.05"
```

Now correct me if I'm wrong, but that is in fact a valid double - and it is recognised as a valid double on my computer, on the emulator and on my own Android device (Nexus 5)

The device that it crashed on was a Galaxy Note II running Android 4.3 - any ideas as to why it might be crashing please?

Comment: Show the code. Likely the user was running with a `Locale` with `,` as decimal separator. Parse your numbers with explicit locales.

Comment: There is a nice section called [Be wary of the default locale](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html) in the `Locale` documentation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is or isn't a valid double depending on your Locale. With a US/ENGLISH locale, `-0.05` is a valid double but with a FRENCH locale for example, it is not (it should be `-0,05` with a comma).

You can see it in action with:

```
NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);
double d = fmt.parse("-0.05").doubleValue(); //-0.05

fmt = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.FRENCH);
d = fmt.parse("-0.05").doubleValue(); //-0.0
d = fmt.parse("-0,05").doubleValue(); //-0.05
```

**EDIT**

However your issue is maybe not that. The minus sign is not valid. You are using `−` instead of `-` (they look the same but are not the same character). Demo:

```
Double.parseDouble("-0.05"); //ok
Double.parseDouble("−0.05"); //exception
```

Comment: My only problem with this is that nearly 50% of my app users' devices use a non-English Locale - so how come this issue has only occurred once, out of thousands of devices, over a period of several months?

Comment: @BenEzard How do you parse the number? `Double.parseDouble`?

Comment: Yep, just that method - and the input String is always formatted with a '.' (guaranteed to be in this format because it's from a file downloaded from my server)

Comment: Unlikely that this is the issue, as it has worked fine on thousands of other devices with the exact same code?

Comment: @BenEzard If you copy paste the string in your question and try to parse it, you will get an error. Maybe the string was generated differently for some reason?

Comment: Indeed you're right - which is weird considering the String is retrieved from a MySQL database from a column with a datatype of Double. 

Ah well, at least we got to the bottom of it - thanks :-)

Comment: You are faced with a Java language restriction ... not what "runs on thousands of devices".  Only the "hyphen" is used as the unary negative operator (and the subtraction dyadic operator), not the long dash

Answer (score 0):

For double constants, the language asks you to use the form  -0.05d  (with the "d" suffix).  See this for [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Also make sure that the symbol intended to be a minus sign is a "hyphen" and not a "long em dash".

Comment: This isn't mandatory though - any floating point number without an "f" or "d" suffixed is automatically determined to be a double - indeed, under the "Floating-Point Literals" section in your link, they write `double d1 = 123.4;`

Comment: And about the minus sign - if it works fine on all other devices, then I presume it's the correct character?